# Admob Error, clearing app data fixes it, but that's not viable

Tags: caching, admob

My Admob adverts are not loading:

```
01-13 00:13:56.942: E/Ads(28232): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not     defined (http://media.admob.com/:1)
01-13 00:13:56.942: E/Web Console(28232): Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined at http://media.admob.com/:1
```

A lot have said that this error means there is no network connection. There certainly is.

Now for the weird part, if I clear the data of the app e.g. Settings/Apps/MyApp/Clear Data, the next time I run the program the adverts will load fine. But obviously I cannot tell my users to clear their data so I can show them adverts!

Any ideas why I have an issue with the app data? And how to fix it.